# Apply rules to columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have quick question. Is there a faster method to replace "for" loop? I want to apply "if" statement to grow out the data. sth like below. "for" loop is way too slow. I need to populate other more complex logic so appreciate any systematic methods to solve it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = pd.DataFrame(index=[np.arange(0,201,1)], columns=['myval'])
for i in s.index:
    if 0<=i<=50:
        s.myval[i] = s.myval[i-1] * 1.05 if i > 0 else 3
    else:
        s.myval[i] = (10 - s.myval[i-1]) * 0.8 + 10 * 0.2
```

Comment: not sure there is a way that is based on the previous value, although I don't know much about pandas.

Comment: @Timescape - Do you try your sample? It doesnt work.

Comment: @jezrael - apologies. should be working now.

Comment: Excel can do way faster than python as the formula is more like build-in. I believe there is a way to apply vectorized calculation but don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply elementwise-python-funciton - pandas built in feature.

Here is the documentation [Pandas element wise operation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#applying-elementwise-python-functions)

Comment: It seems elementwise functions don't allow in-place update meaning I cannot calculate i+1 using i